# PHP Script not updating sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, input

Here is my code.

```
<center>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" name="AwardList" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<script>
function awardSort($ID)
{
document.AwardList.hiddenID.value = $ID;
document.AwardList.submit();
}
</script> 
<table border=1>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenID" />
<tr>  
<th><b>Award</b></th>
<th><b>Issue ID</b></th>
<th><b>Sort #</b></th>
<th><b>Submit</b></th>
</tr>

<?php
$userid = ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
$query = ("select a.*, userdisplayorder, issue_id from award a join award_user aw on a.award_id = aw.award_id where aw.userid = '$userid'");   

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$userdisplayorder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userdisplayorder']);
echo $_POST[hiddenID];
echo '<br>';
echo $userdisplayorder; 

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE award_user SET userdisplayorder='$userdisplayorder' WHERE userid='$userid' AND issue_id='$_POST[hiddenID]'");
}

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$awardimgurl = $row['award_img_url'];
$ID = $row['issue_id'];
$userdisplayorder = $row['userdisplayorder'];

  echo '<tr>';        
  echo '<th>'; echo "<img src='$awardimgurl'>"; echo '</th>';                    
  echo '<th>'; echo '<input type="text" name="issueid" readonly="readonly" value="' . $ID . '" size="5">'; echo '</th>';
  echo '<th>'; echo '<input type="text" name="userdisplayorder" value="' . $userdisplayorder . '" size="5">'; echo '</th>';
  echo '<th>'; echo "<center><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' onclick=awardSort('$ID')></center>"; echo '</th>';
  echo '</tr>';      
}               
?>   
</table> 
</html></center>
```

It looks like this on a webpage:

EDIT: Here is some additional info.

I modified the code to see what it was printing

Results:

The award issue id is fine now.
However, the sort # is not working.
If I change the first award with issue_id 88 to Sort # 3, it will just go back to 0.  However, I can change issue_id 14537's sort # to anything, and it will work.  Say I change issue_id 14537's sort # to 5, then I go and change issue_id 5's sort # to 3, it will go to 5.  It's using whatever value is in Sort # for issue_id 14537 instead of it's own.
I tried to make a function for the $userdisplayorder to make it unique like $ID is, however, i can't figure out how to do two onclick's.

Comment: I don't see any form in your html. All I see is a submit button. Edit: Ok. Now I see it.

Comment: Try to dump the contents of the POST variable at the top and see what values are sent to your script by your form. I prefer the print_r function.

Comment: In your SQL I see update `WHERE userid='$userid' AND issue_id='$issueid'`, is the userid in the row with the issuid? I'm guessing this would not be the case otherwise only the one person (who has the correct userid to match the row) could ever update it.

Comment: @James Yes, this is the case.  Only the person with the correct userid can update their awards (hence I have that where clause).

Comment: @Touch I have updated my original to show you what happens when it is echo'd.  It seems only the last award with issue_id 14537 is being updated by the SQL script.

Comment: @alfredo Just as I thought. You have elements with the same names in the form. So the browser only sends one of them. Try appeding a number to  the name attribute so that it is unique. And then perhaps run a foreach loop which repeats that code for each of the data sent to you. And als test you query in mysql too, to see if it works correctly as pointed out in the comment by James. And if possible, learn PDO instead.

Comment: @Touch Thanks for the info.  I am a novice when it comes to PHP/MySQL and I still need to learn alot of things, so I am trying to go with what I know already (and PDO is not one of them lol).  How can I append a number to the name attribute and do the suggestions you said?

Comment: @Touch Please check my modified code.  I have posted it.  I gave each award their own submit button.  Same problem persists, though.

Comment: @Touch Please check my modified code again.  I figured out how to make the issue_id unique.  That part is working now.  IF I press submit for issue_id 88, it will post 88 for that variable.  However, the sort # (which is $userdisplayorder) is not working cause that one is not unique yet, either.  I tried to make a function for it like I did with issue id however I can't figure out how to put two onclick's in my submit button.

Comment: Oh... So you want it to sort the elements in a order you want? Please provide th structure of you tables.

Comment: Yes.  That is it.  userdisplayorder is a smallint as well as issue_id.  Is there anything else you need?  I also posted a new question that is more detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165864/how-to-make-php-post-variable-unique