# How to make php post variable unique

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, unique

Here is my original code

```
    <center>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" name="AwardList" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> 
    <table border=1>
    <tr>  
    <th><b>Award</b></th>
    <th><b>Issue ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Sort #</b></th>
    <th><b>Submit</b></th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $userid = ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
    $query = ("select a.*, userdisplayorder, issue_id from award a join award_user aw on a.award_id = aw.award_id where aw.userid = '$userid'");   

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $userdisplayorder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userdisplayorder']);
    echo $_POST[issueid];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $userdisplayorder; 

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE award_user SET userdisplayorder='$userdisplayorder' WHERE issue_id='$_POST[issueid]'");
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $awardimgurl = $row['award_img_url'];
    $ID = $row['issue_id'];

    // don't get it from the database since its not unique in the database itself
    // $userdisplayorder = $row['userdisplayorder'];

    echo '<tr>';        
    echo '<th>'; 
    echo "<img src='$awardimgurl'>"; echo '</th>';                    
    echo '<th>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="issueid" readonly="readonly" value="' . $ID . '" size="5">'; 
    echo '</th>';
    echo '<th>'; 
    echo '<input type="text" name="userdisplayorder" value="' . $count . '" size="5">';              
    echo '</th>';
    echo '<th>'; 
    echo "<center><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></center>"; 
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</tr>'; 
    $count ++;     
}   
    ?>   
    </table> 
    </html></center>
```

I need to make the userdisplayorder field unique as well.  I already have the issueid unique.  How can I do this?  Please help me by providing code as well, I am new to PHP and only know basics.  I do not know PDO yet and I am a visual learner
Thank you!

Comment: you can make it an array: name="userdisplayorder[]". Have you tried that ?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are getting value as 0 for the userdisplayorder field from the database itself. You might want to look into it and try to fix it at the database level itself.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Thanks but that did not work.  It first gave off Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given so I just had it post it into the query without escaping and it doesn't work.

Comment: The value is 0 in the database.  The user is supposed to set which value they want (e.g. 1).  If you set it to 1, it doesn't update UNLESS you set the value for 14537 (because it isn't unique)

Comment: based on my first comment, if you are going to make use of arrays then you need to make corresponding changes to your form processing logic too. You also might want to look into what I mentioned in the 2nd comment and see if that helps.

Comment: There is no way to make it work with the current code I already have?  I can remove the current javascript if I can set it up so issue_id as well as the userdisplayorder are unique to their rows.  I am new to this.

Comment: look at the answer that I gave. The problem seems to be in your update query. You don't need to use arrays for userdisplayorder field.

Comment: @Panique I am just using what works.  I am a beginner with PHP.  I don't understand why people are so harsh when I am just trying to use what I know works already.  I don't know where to start with more advanced coding like PDO and MySQLi

Comment: Make your basic code work first and then switch to PDO/MySQLi.

Comment: I agree with @alfredo, some people on stackoverflow don't really care that the OP is actually trying their hardest. This _is_ a beginner question, and they always _could_ do it a different more efficient way, but why be so mean about it?

Comment: PDO is pretty easy to work with.  Easier than mysql, in fact, and a tiny bit more so than mysqli.  My profile contains an example of PDO in action.  (Even that is a little more complicated than it has to be; since statements are traversable, you could say `foreach ($stmt as $row)`.)

Comment: Thanks @pattyd This is how I learned what to do and it works for me.. I can try to learn more advanced code but this is what I know right now and I'm trying to make this work.

Comment: @alfredo No offending! I just found your graphic very nice, because it looked like a typical 1998 style website. You know, the colors, the table borders, the .gifs... This was not about your code!

Comment: @Panique Oh, thanks.  The website actually looks nothing like that, this is just a piece of what is actually on the page.  :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do well to group your items into arrays.

```
for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); ++$i) {

    // I took the liberty of adding HTML-encoding to the output.
    // This prevents issues if a field contains quotes, etc.
    $hrow = array_map('htmlentities', $row);
    extract($hrow, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'html');

    $item_name = "items[$i]";
    echo <<<ENDHTML
    <tr>
     <th><img src="{$html_award_img_url}"></th>
     <th><input type="text" name="{$item_name}[issue_id]" readonly size="5"
               value="{$html_issue_id}"></th>
     <th><input type="text" name="{$item_name}[userdisplayorder]" size="5"
               value="{$html_userdisplayorder}"></th>
     <th><center><input type="submit" name="submitted[{$i}]" value="Submit"></center></th>
    </tr>
ENDHTML;
}
```

At that point, because of how PHP processes forms, `$_POST['items']` will be an array, and each entry of it will itself be an array containing each item field.  It'd be almost like you said `$_POST['items'] = array(0 => array('issue_id' => '3', 'userdisplayorder' => '0'), 1 => array('issue_id'`... .  And `submitted` will be like `array($index_of_row => 'Submit')`.  You can use it to determine which item had its submit button clicked, like so:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submitted'])) {
foreach ($_POST['submitted'] as $key => $unused) {
    $row = $_POST['items'][$key];
    # if you don't want to manually `mysql_real_escape_string` everything...
    $srow = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row);
    ... process $srow ... which now has its own unique userdisplayorder field
}
```

Or if you just want to process all the items each time:

```
if (!empty($_POST['items'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $row) {
        $srow = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row);
        ... process $srow ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. however, I am assuming this is PDO, which I have never touched before.  I have replaced your code with the piece in mine and the table isn't extracting anything from the database.  I will update the original question with the new code, if you could look at it.  :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDO.  It's all to do with how PHP deals with forms.

Comment: You're using `$sql` to refer to your result; my example used `$result`.  Change that variable, and you should be fine.  BTW, it's typically frowned upon to radically change the question's code after posting it; it invalidates other answers.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't know, sorry.  I will just edit in the new code but keep the old code up there as well.  Will change to $result and see what happens

Comment: I changed $query to $result and I'm getting this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given I added the code I'm using with your bits of code to my OP

Comment: @alfredo: Ahh.  I see the issue.  You're setting `$result` to the SQL you're using, rather than the result handle from running the query.  You need to be like `$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,....");`.  For reference, you should do that after you update, so the table shows the updated values rather than the old ones.

Comment: BTW, i'm semi-certain this is more typing than i've done for any question involving `mysql_query`, ever.  :P  I typically just downvote or comment, and move on; i'm only still here because the mysql_query part isn't the main issue.  You really ought to consider reading up on PDO and using it; it makes a lot of this stuff so much easier, and `mysql_query` may disappear from PHP (or at least be moved out of the PHP distribution and into PECL) in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I just want this to work.  I have 2 other scripts that are using plain old mysql_query but they aren't the same as this (they really just select info from db and put it in a table, no submitting).  I updated my original question with the fix and this is what I see now.. http://i.imgur.com/2BJnKAf.png If you'd care to stick around and try to help me fix this, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @alfredo:  Updated; `EXTR_OVERWRITE` seems to ignore the prefix.  Changed to `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`.  (I normally don't use `extract` with a prefix, but i'm also usually doing this stuff in a function.  In the global scope, you definitely want to take precautions.)

Comment: Yay!  Thank you so much so far.  It's looking great.  I guess the last part is submission.  I edited the original question with the current code again.  I don't think I tied the update query in there correctly.

Comment: @alfredo: You're right.  Your item is `$row`, not `$_POST`.  Use `$row[userdisplayorder]`. (Or better yet, `{$row['userdisplayorder']}`, cause that won't trigger notices as long as the field exists.  `$row[userdisplayorder]` will trigger a notice about undefined constants.  One of these days, you're going to want to enable notices.  :))  You'll probably also want to say something like `$srow = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row);` and refer to `$srow` instead of `$row` in your query, to minimize the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Yay thank you it works!! :)  Say I did want to process everything at the same time with just one submit button, I can do that using the second piece of code you provided?

Comment: @alfredo: Yep.  That's the point of putting it in there.  :)  You're actually already providing all the items' info to the server each time anyway.  `$_POST['submitted']` just tells you which item's submit button was clicked, so you know which row to update...but you don't care about that if you're updating everything.

Comment: Very nice.  I will stick with a submit button for each.  I hate to bug you one last time, but do you know how I can set it so you can only have 1 of each number in the field?  For example, I don't want a user to have the same number in their display order.  If they already have the number 1 in a box, don't let them put a 1 in another box (when submitting it will change back to 0)?

Comment: @alfredo: One way would be to keep an array of numbers you've seen, and test whether `intval($srow['userdisplayorder'])` is in that array before trying to update.  If it is, set it to 0; otherwise, add it to the array.  Then continue with the update.  As for preventing it in the form, that's going to require JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE award_user 
SET userdisplayorder='$userdisplayorder' 
WHERE issue_id='$_POST[hiddenID]'");
```

to this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE award_user SET 
userdisplayorder='$userdisplayorder' 
WHERE issue_id='$_POST['issueid']'");
```

Plus you should use MySQLi/PDO in place of mysql_ functions.
Also, I don't think you need JavaScript functions for submitting to the form. You can do that directly. So you can change this:

```
echo '<th>'; echo "<center><input type='submit' 
name='submit' value='Submit' onclick=awardSort('$ID')></center>"; echo '</th>';
```

to this:

```
echo '<th>'; 
echo "<center><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' </center>"; 
echo '</th>';
```

UPDATE. This is when the OP wants to make the userdisplayorder field unique. One way to do that is making changes at the form level like so:

```
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $awardimgurl = $row['award_img_url'];
    $ID = $row['issue_id'];

    // don't get it from the database since its not unique in the database itself
    // $userdisplayorder = $row['userdisplayorder'];

    echo '<tr>';        
    echo '<th>'; 
    echo "<img src='$awardimgurl'>"; echo '</th>';                    
    echo '<th>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="issueid" readonly="readonly" value="' . $ID . '" size="5">'; 
    echo '</th>';
    echo '<th>'; 
    echo '<input type="text" name="userdisplayorder" value="' . $count . '" size="5">';              
    echo '</th>';
    echo '<th>'; 
    echo "<center><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></center>"; 
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</tr>'; 
    $count ++;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the userdisplayfield still isn't unique by row.  How can I do that?  It has to be unique or it's not working.. If I change the 0 to any other number, it's not saving the change unless it's for the award with issue_id 14537 shown in the picture..

Comment: You need additional logic in your mysql query to implement that. Your current logic puts in the database whatever value you are passing through the form. So if you need those values to be unique, then you need to make sure that you are passing unique values for that field through your form.

Comment: Now nothing is unique.  If I press submit for issue_id 88, it is using issue_id 14537 as shown in the picture.  (this happened after removing the javascript)

Comment: How can I make the values unique?  That is what I'm asking.  I was trying to use Javascript  :)  I edited my original question with the code as per your answer.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with JavaScript ?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to make the values unique per row so when you pressed submit for the one row, it used the unique values for the issue_id and the userdisplayorder.  Javascript was one way (use a hidden field and then call the function when you click submit, and pass it through the query).  It was working for the issue_id, however, I needed 2 functions, and couldn't figure out how to call 2 functions with the same submit button (I googled it but it wasn't working with my code).  So I am looking for another way and I'm sure there's another way besides Javascript.  Do you know?

Comment: I like the count.  However, it is still using the last values when I press submit.  e.g. if I want to change the '1' in the display order to a '5', and I press submit for that row, it's submitting data for issue_id 14537 and the '4' in that box.  See here.  http://i.imgur.com/zKxKEwJ.png  then when I press the submit button on the first row: http://i.imgur.com/qSeH01K.png

Comment: I don't think it's going to work at all unless they're unique.